# Can I force my touchscreen monitor to receive touch input without being primary?

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, touchscreen

I looked around to see if someone had a solution to my unique problem, but I only found solutions pointing at Control Panel > Tablet PC Settings > Setup, and this does not work for me. This is my monitor setup and my specs:

*Monitor 1* - AOC 2060W
1600x900
Connected through DVI on the graphics card

*Monitor 2* - a TruTech TV
1440x900
Connected through VGA on the motherboard

*Monitor 3* - Acer FT220HQL
1920x1080
Connected from computer's DVI to monitor's VGA on the motherboard
Touchscreen supporting 10 point touch using USB; Windows labels it "Limited Touch Support"

Monitor 3 is left of Monitor 1, and Monitor 1 is left of Monitor 2; 3 then 1 then 2

I am running Windows 8.1 (Version 6.3 Build 9600)

The Acer is my only touchscreen monitor, and it works correctly... when it is the primary monitor. But I do not want that to be my primary monitor; I use the Acer to watch YouTube videos and I tap the video to quickly pause and play. I want the AOC monitor to be my main monitor because I use it to work on pretty much EVERYTHING but Skype, YouTube, and programs I watch like Bandicam. It is a drag to move windows that cover my videos when they should be appearing on my middle monitor.

But when I make the AOC the primary monitor, the touch input never goes to the Acer, no matter what I do. The Setup button on Tablet PC settings does zip. It works correctly when the Acer is the primary monitor, but not when the AOC is. Here is what happens when I use this button. When the Acer is primary:

1. Text on Acer, I touch the Acer, input goes to Acer
2. I press Enter to send the text to AOC, I touch, input goes to AOC
3. I press Enter again to send the text to TruTech, I touch, input goes to TruTech

When the AOC is primary:

1. Text on AOC, touch, input goes to AOC
2. Text on TruTech, touch, input goes to TruTech
3. Text on Acer, I touch the Acer, **input goes to AOC**, which is wrong!

Note that when AOC is primary, Windows claims that the AOC is the monitor with "Limited Touch Support" and that the Acer has no touch support. Also worth noting is when the TruTech is primary, it has the same behavior when the AOC is primary, with Windows labeling the TruTech with "Limited Touch Support." I tried rearranging the monitors in Windows to see if that would fix it, but they do the same thing. Even arranging them in 1 then 2 then 3 does the same thing.

I have been dealing with this for several months now, and I am finally fed up with it. Is this a bug with Tablet PC Settings, or is there a sneaky set of directions that I am missing? Is it because of the "Limited Touch Support" moving to the primary monitor? I want to know if someone has a similar setup like mine and has ran into this bug or not.

Thanks for reading my issue.

EDIT: I was able to make the AOC my primary monitor while sending touch input to the Acer. The original setup is updated to show what the monitors were connected to. These were changed to the Acer connecting to my motherboard and the AOC and TruTech to the graphics card. The only problem with this is that playing games on my 1080p Acer slow down dramatically because they are running on Intel HD Graphics 4000. So I will need something else other than rewiring the graphic ports.

I want three things to happen: Touch goes to the Acer, the Acer goes to the graphics card, and the AOC is the primary monitor. Is there a possible way of having this happen?